# How to create a Cardano private network

Tags: native-assets, token, sidechains

I need help with a project proposal, but I think this topic could be interesting for many developers and architects.

Does somebody know how to start to build a private Cardano network or where I can find some tutorials?

The idea would be to build a sidechain as layer two, which utilizes the token of the mainnet as the native coin.

Does the idea have sense? Is it possible? Any suggestion?

Many thanks,
Valerio

Comment: For what use do you need it? I think you have two options, either utilize hydra which facilitates isomorfic state channels. Or you could setup a side chain just like cardano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively/additionally, check out the [Making a Shelley Blockchain from Scratch](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/reference/shelley-genesis.md) repo.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create a cardano private network (IMHO) is to clone the cardano-node git hub, start up nix shell, and from there you can start a local cluster.   Works well for me I have a used it many times.

git clone https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node.git

Once nix is completed, you will see the following and type `start-cluster`

```
Commands:
    * nix flake lock --update-input <iohkNix|haskellNix> - update nix build input
    * cardano-cli - used for key generation and other operations tasks
    * wb - cluster workbench
    * start-cluster - start a local development cluster
    * stop-cluster - stop a local development cluster
    * restart-cluster - restart the last cluster run (in 'run/current')
                        (WARNING: logs & node DB will be wiped clean)
```

I also included some tips on how to transfer ada from the gensis address etc. if that would be helpful.  You can go to the tips and tricks section of my readme on The Open Source Cardano Lottery project I created.  https://github.com/lley154/cardano-lottery